# String made from the first char of another string - why is it also printing the full original string?

Tags: c++, string, char, iostream

Learning C++. I just want to grab the first character in a string, then make a new string based on such character, and then print it out:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string name = "Jerry";
    char firstCharacter = name.at(0);
    string stringOfFirstCharacter = string(&firstCharacter);
    cout << stringOfFirstCharacter;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
J
Jerry
```

I don't really know why is it also printing `Jerry`. Why is that?

Comment: Completely unrelated, just looking for information, and not intended as a judgment: did you type `using namespace std;` in the code, or did some tool insert it?

Comment: @PeteBecker: I saw it in some example code a while back, and since then I begun doing it by my own. I used to put it inside each block, but this way seemed more convenient to me. No tool did it. Why, is it a weird practice?

Comment: It's not particularly good (`std::string` is generally better), but I've seen so many code examples that put the same using declaration directly after the `#include`s that I suspect some tool is doing it. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's commonly found in beginner C++ books, which often inadequately explain that they've done it to make their code samples simpler, and not because it is good practice.

Comment: @JBentley - too bad. But I'm struck by the consistency of seeing it **immediately** after the `#include`s: no blank line, as if it's just automatically part of the `#include` directives.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Hey, actually, I found a tool that does insert that line after the imports! Code::Blocks, when creating a new console application with C++, gives you the following program: http://pastebin.com/DdgxuBa9

Comment: @Omega - thanks. I do see lots of people using Code::Blocks here. It's a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. The signature of the constructor that takes a pointer to `char` requires that it is a pointer to a *null terminated* string, which it is not in your case since it is a single character.

My guess is that the implementation you have uses the small object optimization, and that "Jerry" is small enough that it is stored inside the `std::string` object rather than dynamically allocated. The layout of the two objects in the stack happens to be first `firstCharacter`, then `name`. When you call `std::string(&firstCharacter)` it reads until it hits the first null character (inside the `std::string` buffer) and stops there.

Comment: Nice answer, +1 for figuring out why it gave that output.

Answer (score 3):

You are constructing an [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) object from a `char*` (because you are taking the address of `firstCharacter`). A pointer to a character is not interpreted as a character itself by the constructor of `std::string`, but rather as a null-terminated string.

In this case, your program has **Undefined Behavior**, because the address of `firstCharacter` is not the address of the first character of a null-terminated string.

What you should be doing is:

```
string stringOfFirstCharacter(1, firstCharacter);
cout << stringOfFirstCharacter;
```

If you really want to create a one-character string. However, notice that in order to print the character to the standard output, you could have simply written:

```
cout << firstCharacter;
```

Or even:

```
cout << name.at(0);
```

Comment: +1.  I'd prefer "null-terminated" (lower case) or "`\0`-terminated", though.  `NULL` makes me think of the null pointer constant.

Answer (score 2):

With `string(&firstCharacter)`, you are using the [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of the form

```
std::string( const char* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

That form expects a pointer to a *null-terminated array of characters*.  It is incorrect to pass a pointer to character(s) that are not null-terminated.

With your intention of initializing the string with 1 `char`, you should use the form:

```
string( 1, firstCharacter )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `string` constructor you're using (the one that takes a `char *` argument), is intended to convert a C-style string into a C++ string object - not a single character.  By passing it a single character you cause undefined behaviour.

In your specific case, there appears to not be a zero byte in memory after `firstCharacter`, so the constructor runs through and includes all of `name` along with it!